# Grep doesn't work

Tags: shell, unix, grep

This don't work for me

```
grep -vE '^\..*' tmp1.txt >grep.txt
grep -vE '^le-.*\.sh' grep.txt >tmp1.txt
```

tmp1.txt before

```
.config
le-test.sh
a b c
```

after

```
.config
le-test.sh
a b c
```

anyone help ?

Comment: What is your desired result ?

Comment: i wanna filter le-test.sh and .config...
> a b c

Comment: so you do NOT want .config or le-test.sh ?

Comment: yeah i wanna ignore hidden files and files started with le- and ending with .sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the grep you'd use: `grep -vE "^\.|^le-[^.]+\.sh" FILE`

Comment: this is **not** 100% correct for OP's requirement. e.g. there is another line `foole-bar.sh`, this line would be filtered out as well. from OP's code, it seems that he just wants line  `^le-...` to get removed. pls fix it.

Comment: @Kent - good catch.  Changed.

Comment: FYI: The `[^.]+` part of your regex means that `le-foo.bar.sh` would escape your filter.

Answer (score 1):

What do you see when you run:

```
$ grep -vE '^\.' tmp1.txt
le-test.sh
a b c
$ grep -E '^\.' tmp1.txt
.config
$
```

(the trailing `.*` on the regex doesn't add or remove any lines of data).  You should see what I show; if you're really not seeing what I show, then you need to start looking at what your version of `grep` does with the `-E` option.  It should be enabling '`egrep`-mode' with extended regular expressions, not that your regular expressions are extended.  Try:

```
$ grep -e '^\.' tmp1.txt
.config
$ grep -ve '^\.' tmp1.txt
le-test.sh
a b c
$
```

The lower case `-e` simply says the next argument is the regular expression.  If you are still not getting the output shown, then you're probably not using a regular version of `grep`.  You'll need to review what you are running.  You could try running `/usr/bin/grep` or test whether it is the GNU version with `grep --version`, etc.

Assuming you can get the output shown for the first phase of filtration, then the second phase should work too.  You say you want to eliminate 'files starting with `le-` and ending in `.sh`', but your second regex only requires `.sh` after the `le-` start; it doesn't specify the end:

```
$ grep -vE '^\.' tmp1.txt | grep -E '^le-.*\.sh$'
le-test.sh
$ grep -vE '^\.' tmp1.txt | grep -vE '^le-.*\.sh$'
a b c
$
```

One possible cause of grief would be if your data file has Windows line endings (CRLF) but you're running the test on Unix.  The `\.sh$` part of the regex would fail because there's also a CR (carriage return, `'\r'`) before the end of the line.  However, that shouldn't affect the first part of the filter process.

You should be able to do it all in one command with:

```
$ grep -E '^(\.|le-.*.sh$)' tmp1.txt
.config
le-test.sh
$ grep -vE '^(\.|le-.*.sh$)' tmp1.txt
a b c
$
```

This version does need the `-E` flag; the alternation `|` and the parentheses for grouping require it.